# Discord.js: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am creating a Discord music bot using discord.js version 13.6.0 and discord-player but I keep getting this error, here is my code:

```js
const { MessageEmbed, Permissions } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'stop',
    aliases: [],
    utilisation: '{prefix}stop',
    voiceChannel: true,

    execute(client, message) {
        if (message.member.id.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.KICK_MEMBERS)) {
            // Stop the player
        };
    },
};
```

The error I get when running that command:

```
if(message.member.id.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.KICK_MEBERS)){
```

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has')

I don't know why this is happening, please could someone help me?

Comment: `String(...)` around `message.member.id` seems odd. Why are you doing this?

Comment: @IgorShmukler sorry, that was an old error, i've updated it to be the actual error, didn't realise

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read permissions from the `member.id`.

If you take a look at the [DiscordJS Documentation for member](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember), and look at the available properties, it has both `id` and `permissions`.

So, changing your line to `message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.KICK_MEBERS)` instead of `message.member.id.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.KICK_MEBERS)` should fix this for you.